# Prove: $f$ is continuous iff $f_{+}(x)$ and $f_{-}(x)$ are continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$

We would like to show that $f$ is continuous iff $f_{+}(x)$ and $f_{-}(x)$ are both continuous, given:

$$  
f_{+}(x) :=
  \begin{cases}
                                   f(x) & \text{if $f(x) \geq 0$} \\
                                   0 & \text{otherwise} \\
  \end{cases}
$$

$$  
f_{-}(x) :=
  \begin{cases}
                                   -f(x) & \text{if $f(x) \leq 0$} \\
                                   0 & \text{otherwise} \\
  \end{cases}
$$

Hints?

Comment: If we are given that $f_+$ and $f_-$ are continuous the only "problem" is at x= 0.

Comment: @user247327 Why should $x=0$ be a problem?

Comment: Because I misread the problem!  I thought it said "for $x\ge 0$" and "for $x\le 0$" rather than f(x).  And it really annoys me that a carriage return posts the comment!  I keep pressing carriage return before I intend to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has

$$f(x)=f_+(x)-f_-(x)$$

Indeed when $x$ is such that $f(x)\geq 0$, $f_+(x)=f(x)$ and $f_-(x)=0$; when $x$ is such that $f(x)\leq 0$, $f_-(x)=-f(x)$ and $f_+(x)=0$.

From this identity we derive immediately that when $f_\pm$ are continuous than $f$, being the sum of two continuous functions is continuous.

For the converse assume now that $f$ is continuous. $f_+(x)=\operatorname{max}(f(x),0)$ and $f_-(x)=\max(-f(x),0)$. And so they are continuous as the maximum of two continuous functions.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: If $f,g$ are continuous, then so are $f+g$ and $\max\{f,g\}$.

Comment: And also $f-g$.